# SQL Like pattern

Tags: sql

I apply a `left` statement into field that need to one specified value if the result of the `left` operation is any char like 0 to 9, or X or Y.

The statement is

`select case when T like '50%' and left(value,1) like '[0-9 X-Y]%'  then 'Approved'`

Is this pattern correct?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it?  Do you get he right results?

Comment: That is correct...

Comment: If you have a space in your pattern `'[0-9 X-Y]%'`, then you will also match anything that starts with a space. If that is the required behaviour then great, if not, you will need to make your pattern `'[0-9X-Y]%'`

Comment: Just about every database has some form of Regular Expressions that can do exactly that. In Postgres they're used with the `~` operator, in MySQL it's `RLIKE`, in Oracle it's done with functions. The SQL standard one is `SIMILAR TO`, but it's support is also limited.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL `LIKE` doesn't allow ranges like `[0-9 X-Y]`, you have to use `REGEX` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do one of:

```
select (case when T like '50%' and left(value, 1) like '[0-9 X-Y]' then 'Approved' . . .
```

or:

```
select (case when T like '50%' and value like '[0-9 X-Y]%' then 'Approved' . . .
```

There is generally no reason to mix `left()` with `like`.

Your version is *technically* correct.  But the pattern is general (can match strings of any length) and you are only comparing to the first character in the pattern.  That makes the statement awkward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is true, I did not think about that.